# Query count with three joining table

Tags: sql

I been trying to figure this out all afternoon. I'm not even sure if it's possible with the current database structure. I've tried the following statement but it didn't return what I need. The problem with the statement below is that it only returns the projectType if it exists. I need to return zero if the projectType doesn't exists. Any help is much appreciated.

```
SELECT r.region, ISNULL(o.totalcount,0) AS TotalCount, o.projectType
  FROM region r 
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(o2.id) AS TotalCount, o2.regionID, t2.projectType
      FROM projects o2 
      RIGHT JOIN projectTypes t2 on o2.typeID = t2.id
      GROUP BY o2.regionId, t2.projectType
  ) o ON r.id = o.regionId
  ORDER by r.Region
```

```
regions:
-------------------------
id  | region    |
-------------------------
1   | East      |
-------------------------
2   | MidWest   |
-------------------------
3   | West      |
-------------------------


Project Type:
-------------------------
id  | projectType   | 
-------------------------
1   | Web Desgin    |
-------------------------
2   | Database  |
-------------------------
3   | Development   |
-------------------------


Projects:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
id  | projectName   | regionID  | projectTypeID | postedOn  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | Project 1 | 1     | 2     | 2012-09-02    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2   | Project 2 | 2     | 2     | 2012-09-02    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
3   | Project 3 | 1     | 1     | 2012-09-02    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
4   | Project 4 | 3     | 2     | 2012-09-02    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
5   | Project 5 | 3     | 1     | 2012-10-02    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
6   | Project 6 | 3     | 2     | 2012-10-02    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
7   | Project 7 | 3     | 3     | 2012-10-02    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
8   | Project 8 | 2     | 3     | 2012-10-02    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
9   | Project 9 | 1     | 2     | 2012-10-02    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
10  | Project 10    | 1     | 2     | 2012-10-02    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------



Desired Results:
-----------------------------------------
Region  | project Type  | totalCount    |
-----------------------------------------
East    | Web Desgin    | 1     | 
-----------------------------------------
East    | Database  | 3     |
-----------------------------------------
East    | Development   | 0     |
-----------------------------------------
Midwest | Web Desgin    | 0     | 
-----------------------------------------
Midwest | Database  | 2     |
-----------------------------------------
Midwest | Development   | 1     |
-----------------------------------------
West    | Web Desgin    | 1     | 
-----------------------------------------
West    | Database  | 2     |
-----------------------------------------
West    | Development   | 1     |
-----------------------------------------
```

Comment: I assume you want a report listing (region, project type, number of projects) tuples?

Comment: Yes, I want to count the numbers of projects per region and project types. thank you

Comment: Ah, I see it says right there, if I'd only scrolled down. Right then. Answer coming shortly.

Comment: Ouch, they beat me to it. Oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not

```
SELECT regions.region, projectTypes.projectType,
       (SELECT count(*) FROM projects
        WHERE projects.typeID = projectTypes.id
          AND projects.regionID = regions.id) as totalCount
FROM regions, projectTypes
```

Comment: Thanks Marlin for your response, I ended up using your suggestion because I was able to add in additional where statement. I tried the same with the previous suggestion but it did not return all projectTypes. Thanks again for your suggestion! Cheers...

Comment: SELECT regions.region, projectTypes.projectType,
       (SELECT count(*) FROM projects
        WHERE projects.typeID = projectTypes.id
          AND projects.regionID = regions.id AND projects.postedOn >= '2012-10-03 00:00:00' and projects.postedOn < '2012-10-04 00:00:00') as totalCount
FROM regions, projectTypes

Answer (score 4):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6680f/1

```
SELECT r.region
  , pt.projectType 
  , count(p.id)
FROM region r cross join ProjectTypes pt

  left join projects p on p.regionID = r.id and pt.id = p.TypeID

group by r.region, pt.projectType
order by r.region
```

Comment: Wow, that’s exactly what I’m looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: It didn't return every projectTypes when I added an additional where clause. SELECT r.region
  , pt.projectType 
  , count(p.id)
FROM region r cross join ProjectTypes pt

  left join projects p on p.regionID = r.id and pt.id = p.TypeID
where p.postedOn >= '2012-10-04 00:00:00' and p.postedOn < '2012-10-05 00:00:00'
group by r.region, pt.projectType
order by r.region

Comment: Nice one.  Cleaner than a select in the select phrase.

Comment: To add an additional where condition, you might have to add it in the on section.